# Interval search for messages in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to split the found messages into intervals. Can this be done with Elasticsearch?
For example. There are 10 messages, you need to divide them into 3 intervals. It should look like this...
**[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]** => {**[0,1,2]**, **[3,4,5,6]**, **[7,8,9]**}.
I'm only interested in the beginning of the intervals. For example: {**[count - 3, min 0]**, **[count - 4, min 3]**, **[count - 3, min - 7]**}

Example.

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
  }
}

POST /test_index/_doc/0
{
  "id": 0
}

POST /test_index/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1
}

POST /test_index/_doc/2
{
  "id": 2
}

POST /test_index/_doc/3
{
  "id": 3
}

POST /test_index/_doc/4
{
  "id": 4
}

POST /test_index/_doc/5
{
  "id": 5
}

POST /test_index/_doc/6
{
  "id": 6
}

POST /test_index/_doc/7
{
  "id": 7
}

POST /test_index/_doc/8
{
  "id": 8
}

POST /test_index/_doc/9
{
  "id": 9
}
```

It is necessary to divide the values ​​into 3 intervals with the same number of elements in each interval:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "result": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "min": 0.0,
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "min": 3.0,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "min": 7.0,
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is a similar function: "variable width histogram":

```
GET /test_index/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "variable_width_histogram": {
        "field": "id",
        "buckets": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

But "variable width histogram" separates documents by id value, not by the number of elements in the bucket

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mapping is like:

```
{
  "some_numeric_field" : {"type" : "integer"}
}
```

Then you can build histograms out of it with fixed interval sizes:

```
POST /my_index/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "some_numeric_field": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "some_numeric_field",
        "interval": 7
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "prices": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 0.0,
          "doc_count": 7
        },
        {
          "key": 7.0,
          "doc_count": 7
        },
        {
          "key": 14.0,
          "doc_count": 7
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To get the individual values inside each bucket, just add a sub-aggregation, maybe "top_hits" or anything else like a "terms"
aggregation.

Without knowing more about your data, I really cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not quite what I need.

Comment: I intentionally mentioned the "histogram aggregation" and NOT the "Variable width histogram". You cannot get fixed sized buckets by any means in elasticsearch. I specified the interval as 7 , based on your dataset, which implied a linear set of points starting from 0 -> 14. Your question can only be solved by a histogram, knowing the data-distribution ahead of time. You can change the interval to 4 or another arbitary value, by first calculating the spread of the values, using mean and median. But there is no way to get fixed sized buckets withotu knowing the interval ahead of time.

Comment: Is there a way to add numbering to the query results?

Comment: What do you mean by numbering? Pls add an example

Comment: document numbering like row_number() in postgresql